# Wordpress getting template for post category type to work

Tags: wordpress

Hiall,

In my wordpress site I have a Category called “meetings”, and it’s slug is “meeting”, also its ID is 27.

I create a default post article and then select “Meeting” from the categories panel and then publish etc.

Reading here 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display

If I create a template file called category-meetings.php or category-27.php then it should pick those files up and use them for a template layout for my selected Meeting category posts etc???

But for whatever reason I can not get it to do this.

I have also tried changing the permalinks settings from “post name” to  custom structre with /%category%/%postname%/

but again no luck.

Am I missing something here?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to target a single post, whereas your template is targeting the category archive pages. For example, look at this diagram of the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/96/wp-template-hierarchy.jpg).

You could: 
1) Create that post as a page and then create a template just for that page. 
2) Create a custom post type and create a custom template for that custom post type.

Comment: Thanks @spnzr I think you are correct there, in the docs it does say when you name a file eg category-meeting.php it is only for the "Archive" of that category? But how do you target a single post using that way? I was able to achieve what I wanted with your second suggestion spnzr using custom post types etc, but would be nice to know how to get the  category-meeting.php for single posts to work etc

Comment: I think the thinking is that a single post shouldn't require a separate template and if it does it should be a custom post type. You can use CSS to target different taxonomies. You can also use conditionals in the templates, for example: `if ( in_category( $category ) ){ // special category code; }`.

Answer (score 1):

The naming has to match your slug. I would change

```
category-meetings.php
```

to

```
category-meeting.php
```

And make sure the category-customname.php files are in the same directory as the default category.php file.

**Addition/Revision**

For a custom page for a single post -- find the post number, let's say 999, then create a single page with the past number appended to the file name in the same directory where the single.php file exists. This worked up to WP ver 3.2-ish. Unless it's been deprecated, it should still work.

```
single-999.php
```

Comment: Hi Valerie I made sure my name was matching my slug, but still no luck, it looks like the template only works for the categories "archive page"??? Thats the only page this category-meeting.php template loads for me. See response below.

Comment: That's a hint.  So category-meeting.php is loaded? What is the full url when that happens?

Comment: From reading through all the comments here, I have a question. What is it you want to see, in regular words? I revised my answer w/ additional text.